# How can an array be safely passed from one thread to another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, thread-safety

I'm working with some audio processing which is not done on the main thread. My background thread repeatedly generates arrays of floats that my main thread will want to use to display something to the user. Will this be thread safe or is it oversimplified? Since this is in an OpenGL loop, I want to avoid blocking either thread with `atomic` locking.

I'm flexible with the storage format. (C array, NSArray, etc. and double, CGFloat, NSNumber, etc.)

Note that each time the second method is called, it may or may not have actual new data to process. It just wants whatever the latest is.

```
@interface

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *generatedNumbers;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *passedNumbers;
...

@end

@implementation

//This is called over and over repeatedly and an unpredictable rate
- (void) generateSomeNumbers{
    ...
    [self.generatedNumbers removeAllObjects];
    for (Something x in something){
        ...
        [self.generatedNumbers addObject:someNSNumberOrCGFloat];
    }
}

//This is called from the main thread (opengl CADisplayLink)
- (void) doStuffWithLatestGeneratedNumbers{
    self.passedNumbers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.generatedNumbers];
    [self doStuffWithNumbers:self.passedNumbers];
}
```

Or how about this?:

```
@interface

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *generatedNumbers;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *passedNumbers;
...

@end

@implementation

//This is called over and over repeatedly and an unpredictable rate
- (void) generateSomeNumbers{
    ...
    [self.generatedNumbers removeAllObjects];
    for (Something x in something){
        ...
        [self.generatedNumbers addObject:someNSNumberOrCGFloat];
    }

    [self copyNumbers:self.generatedNumbers];
}

- (void)copyNumbers:(NSArray *)numbers
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.passedNumbers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.generatedNumbers];
                });
    }
}

//This is called from the main thread (opengl CADisplayLink)
- (void) doStuffWithLatestGeneratedNumbers{

    [self doStuffWithNumbers:self.passedNumbers];
}
```

Comment: This may be a pedantic comment, but your `@property` definition of `NSMutableArray` and `NSArray` is missing the pointer...

Comment: Yeah, just saw that. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since this is in an OpenGL loop, I want to avoid blocking either
>   thread with atomic locking

This makes things much harder. You will need to take some kind of lock unless the operation to swap the array value is atomic (ie. a single CPU instruction).

If you're dealing with values that are larger than the native instruction size of the CPU, the operation to assign a replacement will not be atomic.

Assigning an NSMutableArray pointer *is* atomic, but unless you are happy to leak the array it's replacing, you'll need to release the existing array. The combination of these two operations is not atomic, so needs to be protected with a lock (which is what marking the property as `atomic` does).

I'd recommend double-checking that you can't take a lock here. [The lock in question is a spin-lock protecting two instructions](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/Accessors.subproj/objc-accessors.mm), so it's going to be very cheap even when contended. If you're using Objective-C, or allocating any memory from the heap at all, you're probably already working at too high a level of abstraction to worry about this sort of detail (doing any of things already involves taking locks).

An example of a situation where taking locks, using Objective-C, or even allocating memory is to be avoided is in realtime auto processing. Since the duration of a lock is not completely predictable and realtime audio threads have extremely tight deadlines (tighter than an OpenGL loop --- sometimes less than 1ms, with any overrun causing audible glitches), they can't be used safely. The standard way of passing data between threads then is a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Comment: You said the lock is cheap when contended. But won't the lock last for the time it takes to copy all values of the array? Unfortunately, I am working with audio processing. I'm generating an FFT array in the audio thread, and then the OpenGL thread is processing it. I think the OpenGL thread can afford to be the one doing most of the data crunching.

Comment: No, the protected lines of C are `oldValue = *slot; *slot = newValue;`. Everything else happens outside the spinlock.

Comment: Just to clarify, my comment about audio processing was about processing sound to be *played* in realtime. From what you've described, it sounds like you're not playing the audio you're processing so you're probably working with different latency requirements (I'm not sure what they are, but I imagine that occasionally dropping below 60fps isn't the disaster that a dropped audio sample is).

Comment: I'm trying to play audio while also calculating an FFT to be displayed in a visualization. The documentation for AVFoundation says not to use any locks because they will cause stutters in audio playback. But I fail to see how an occasional wait for a spin-lock like you described would have any significance at all in comparison to calculating an FFT. Seems like it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
@property (strong) NSArray* generatedNumbers;

....

- (void) generateSomeNumbers{
    NSMutableArray* tempNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (Something x in something){
        ...
        [tempNumbers addObject:someNSNumberOrCGFloat];
    }

    [self setGeneratedNumbers: tempNumbers];
}

//This is called from the main thread (opengl CADisplayLink)
- (void) doStuffWithLatestGeneratedNumbers{

    [self doStuffWithNumbers: [self generatedNumbers]];
}
```

The above assumes that `generatedNumbers` is not ever mutated after the assignment in generateNumbers and also we are using ARC.

Note that the property is atomic.  I think this is necessary to stop a potential race condition where the main thread tries to get `generatedNumbers` but the array is deallocated by the other thread before it has a chance to do the retain.

Comment: Making the property as `copy` would guarantee that the array isn't mutated.

Comment: @ChrisDevereux Yes, and if you did, the property could be nonatomic.  However, Im assuming that copying the whole array would be quite expensive.

Comment: Agree about copying the array. I think it would still need to be marked atomic to avoid the race condition though, as loading the existing value to release + replacing the existing value is not atomic.

Comment: In this particular case, I'm not terribly concerned about copying the array -it's not huge. I feel more concerned about blocking between the threads, because that could cause uneven framerate. So I guess I could go the `copy` route. But is the copy operation itself safe to do with the auto-synthesized setter? What happens if the OpenGL thread is reading the numbers from the array as a new array is being assigned? I suppose it's reading from a different area of memory than what's now assigned to the generatedNumbersReference, but could that get deallocated while it's still operating on it?

Comment: @Tenfour04 copying the array requires a call to malloc, which requires taking a lock

Comment: @Tenfour04 The lock will only be held while the object pointer for the property value is being assigned or being read.  Also, the locks used to make properties atomic are pretty lightweight.

Comment: What I mean is, in this sample code, what happens if the generate numbers method reassigns the array pointer to a new object while the do stuff method is still reading data from it? Is it possible for it to get deallocated since it no longer has any references to it, or does the retain count stay above 0 until the doStuff method completes?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Nothing.  The do Stuff method has its own strong reference to the original array.

Comment: OK, I think I understand. The argument of the method doStuffWithNumbers: is a strong reference that lasts until the end of the method (as long as it isn't reassigned), right?